# There is a difference in performance or resource usage when using parentheses

Tags: performance, parentheses

In the following example:

```
bool res = (aux > 0 && aux < 10);
```

**Parentheses** are used for clarity. The same result is obtained by doing:

```
bool res = aux > 0 && aux < 10;
```

Are there differences in performance or use of resources?

Comment: Assuming this code is a C or C++ code and it is optimized (with a descent compiler), then the resulting binary will be the same for both code. More generally, you should not care about such things: write your code for clarity first.

Comment: Example it's for C# application. Thanks for comments.

Comment: It should be the same for C#. You can check the [intermediate language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) to be sure they are equivalent.